# Rails Fake-S3 on CircleCI Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, paperclip, circleci

I'm trying to configure Fake-S3 with Paperclip following [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ktopping/4762011). On development machine everything works fine, but when I'm trying to run it on CircleCI I'm getting error

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "local-bucket.local.s3.endpoint" port 4567
```

I have the next config/environments/test.rb:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    access_key_id: 'anything',
    secret_access_key: 'anything'
  },
  bucket: 'local-bucket',
  s3_host_name: 'local.s3.endpoint',
  s3_protocol: 'http',
  url: ':s3_alias_url',
  s3_host_alias: 'local-bucket.local.s3.endpoint:4567',
  path: '/test/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
  s3_options: {
    use_ssl: false,
    s3_port: 4567
  }
}
```

On CircleCI I'm adding that line to /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 local-bucket.local.s3.endpoint
```

And running next command:

```
fakes3 -r ./fakes3 -p 4567 >log/fakes3.log 2>&1 &
```

So, when I'm trying to create new bucket with next code:

```
  s3 = AWS::S3.new(
    access_key_id:     'anything',
    secret_access_key: 'anything',
    s3_endpoint:       'local.s3.endpoint',
    s3_port:           4567,
    use_ssl:           false
)
s3.buckets.create('local-bucket')
```

I'm getting next error:

```
rake aborted!
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "local-bucket.local.s3.endpoint" port 4567
/home/ubuntu/***/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.64.0/lib/aws/core/http/connection_pool.rb:327:in `start_session'
/home/ubuntu/***/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.64.0/lib/aws/core/http/connection_pool.rb:127:in `session_for'
/home/ubuntu/***/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.64.0/lib/aws/core/http/net_http_handler.rb:56:in `handle'
/home/ubuntu/***/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.64.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:253:in `block in make_sync_request'
/home/ubuntu/***/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.64.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:282:in `retry_server_errors'
/home/ubuntu/***/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.64.0/lib/aws/s3/region_detection.rb:11:in `retry_server_errors'
/home/ubuntu/***/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.64.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:249:in `make_sync_request'
/home/ubuntu/***/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.64.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:511:in `block (2 levels) in client_request'
/home/ubuntu/***/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.64.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:391:in `log_client_request'
/home/ubuntu/***/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.64.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:477:in `block in client_request'
/home/ubuntu/***/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.64.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:373:in `return_or_raise'
/home/ubuntu/***/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.64.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:476:in `client_request'
(eval):3:in `create_bucket'
/home/ubuntu/***/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.64.0/lib/aws/s3/bucket_collection.rb:109:in `create'
/home/ubuntu/***/lib/tasks/fakes3.rake:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => fakes3:create_bucket
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Please, help me to figure out what's wrong?

UPDATED(1):

I realized that if I connect to CircleCI build via SSH and run

```
fakes3 -r ./fakes3 -p 4567 >log/fakes3.log 2>&1 &
```

from rails app folder everything works as needed and all tests passes.

UPDATED(2):

Piece of circle.yml file:

```
test:
  pre:
    - bundle exec fakes3 -r ./fakes3 -p 4567 >./log/fakes3.log 2>&1 &
    - bundle exec rake fakes3:create_bucket
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After couple days looking for a decision I found it.
The problem was in running FakeS3 in background using & sign

```
fakes3 -r ./fakes3 -p 4567 >log/fakes3.log 2>&1 &
```

Following [this docs](https://circleci.com/docs/background-process) from CircleCI:

> Starting a background process from circle.yml is entirely possible, but it is not done by adding & to the end of your command line. Instead, you set the background flag on the command.

So, I rewrote FakeS3 launching following way:

```
test:
  pre:
    - bundle exec fakes3 -r ./fakes3 -p 4567 >./log/fakes3.log 2>&1:
        background: true
    - bundle exec rake fakes3:create_bucket
```

and got a result.